# Mule flow -- java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class sun.nio.cs.UTF_8 from class sun.nio.cs.UTF_8ConstructorAccess

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am facing this error when I try to launch my application

```
ERROR 2015-11-12 10:47:14,521 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
  java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class sun.nio.cs.UTF_8
  from class sun.nio.cs.UTF_8ConstructorAccess
```

Any idea why ? I was able to fix it by reinstalling studio but it resurfaced.
Please help.

My config xml-

```html
<batch:job name="ProcessConfigFiles" max-failed-records="-1">
        <batch:input>
            <file:inbound-endpoint path="${config.path}" connector-ref="FileConfiguration" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Get config files" pollingFrequency="${config.polling}" fileAge="${config.minfileage}">              
                <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="${config.pattern}" />
            </file:inbound-endpoint>
            <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="java.util.List"/>
            <logger message="#['Filemover configuration: ' + message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger" />
        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="SendRequestsToQueue" accept-expression="#[payload.status == 'active']">
                <logger level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger" message="#['Request: ' + payload.name] and #['FilePattern:' + payload.filePattern]"/>
                <choice doc:name="Choice">
                    <when expression="#[(payload.srcType == 'file') || (payload.srcType == 'sftp')]">
                        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
                        <amqp:outbound-endpoint queueName="${amqp.fileMoverQueue}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FileMoveRequestQueue"/>
                    </when>
                    <when expression="#[payload.srcType == 'pgp']">
                        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
                        <amqp:outbound-endpoint queueName="${amqp.fileMoverPGPQueue}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FileMovePGPRequestQueue"/>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <logger message="Default Choice" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                    </otherwise>
                </choice>
            </batch:step>
            <batch:step name="OnError" accept-policy="ONLY_FAILURES">
                 <set-variable variableName="RequestKeyID" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" doc:name="RequestKeyID"/>
          <set-variable variableName="BatchKeyID" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" doc:name="BatchKeyID"/>
          <set-variable variableName="TroubleShootInfo" value="#['Filemover configuration: ' + message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" doc:name="TroubleShootInfo"/>
         <set-variable variableName="ConditionID" value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]" doc:name="ConditionID"/>
            <set-variable variableName="Severity" value="Red Alert" doc:name="Severity" />
          
                <flow-ref name="errorflow" doc:name="errorflow"/>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#['Total Requests: ' + payload.totalRecords + ' Requests sent to queue: ' + payload.successfulRecords]"/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>
    <sub-flow name="errorflow">
    <logger message="&quot;Inside the Error Flow for the interface&quot; #[payload.name] &quot;and file pattern :&quot; #[payload.filePattern]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <tracking:custom-event event-name="Error Processing request" doc:name="Error Business Event">
            <tracking:meta-data key="Exception" value="#[exception.cause]"/>
            <tracking:meta-data key="Filename" value="#[payload.filePattern]"/>
            <tracking:meta-data key="Interface" value="#[payload.name]"/>
            <tracking:meta-data key="SourceHost" value="#[payload.srcHost]"/>
            <tracking:meta-data key="SourcePath" value="#[payload.srcPath]"/>
            <tracking:meta-data key="DestinationHost" value="#[payload.destHost]"/>
            <tracking:meta-data key="DestinationPath" value="#[payload.destPath]"/>
        </tracking:custom-event>
        <set-variable variableName="Severity" value="Red Alert" doc:name="Severity"/>
        <flow-ref name="SendAlertNotify" doc:name="ExceptionAlertNotify"/>
        <flow-ref name="MoveFileErrorPath" doc:name="MoveFileErrorPath"/>
        <!-- <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <amqp:outbound-endpoint queueName="${amqp.fileMover.dead-letter}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Dead-LetterQueue"/> -->
    </sub-flow>
</mule>
```